# Guarantee no padding between structure members to use structure as an array

Tags: c++, structure, padding

Is it always save to call `float z = data.AllCoordinates()[2]` in the example below?

```
struct Data {
    // data members
   float x, y, z;
    // data members
   float* AllCoordinates() { return &x; }
} data;
```

If not, how to guarantee lack of gaps between structure members? So part of the structure can be used like an array.

Comment: *guarantee. And you can't, at least not in a standard way. Nonstandard extensions include the horrible `__attribute__((packed))` et al, but I'm not sure if this would be undefined behavior even then. Just don't to this.

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't.

Why not just declare the struct to contain an array if you want it to behave like an array? Add e.g. `float & x() { return array[0]; }` if you wish.

Comment: Or `operator[]` for array-like access.

Comment: @DyP agreed, although that doesn't guarantee no padding.